install wine winehq-stable = E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
when i tried to type: "sudo apt-get install wine winehq-stable" it says what i have held broken packages
wine --version
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
wine64 --version
wine-6.0.3 (Ubuntu 6.0.3~repack-1)
i got
https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu/ (jamal)
Some community members have suggested similar questions that may solve your problem.
Do any of these answer your question?
How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA? (14 answers)

What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file? (5 answers)

thats all is not working, everytime, when i'm trying to do something, its display this:
> mbr@MBR:~$ sudo wget -NP /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
> https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
> --2024-05-19 19:15:39--  https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/dists/jammy/winehq-jammy.sources
> Resolving dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)... 146.75.118.217 Connecting
> to dl.winehq.org (dl.winehq.org)|146.75.118.217|:443... connected.
> HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 304 Not Modified File
> ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources’ not modified on server.
> Omitting download.
> 
> mbr@MBR:~$ sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable Reading
> package lists... Done Building dependency tree... Done Reading state
> information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may
> mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are
> using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not
> yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following
> information may help to resolve the situation:
> 
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  winehq-stable :
> Depends: wine-stable (= 9.0.0.0~mantic-1) W: Target Packages
> (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
> (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target Packages
> (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
> Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_US) is configured multiple
> times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
> Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times
> in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
> (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target DEP-11
> (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
> DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple
> times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
> DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times
> in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target
> DEP-11-icons-hidpi (main/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar) is configured
> multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
> (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 W: Target CNF
> (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in
> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/archive_uri-https_dl_winehq_org_wine-builds_ubuntu_-jammy.list:1
> and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/winehq-jammy.sources:1 E: Unable to
> correct problems, you have held broken packages.

its only says "multiple times", that's really annoying, i hate it
what i have to do?

Does this answer your question? What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?

https://launchpad.net/~wine/+archive/ubuntu/wine-builds is deprecated and does not provide support for 22.04 (jammy)

Does this answer your question? How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?

Fix your sources and you won't see the "multiple times" warning. Undo everything you have done and install the version of wine in the Ubuntu repos, and it will work.
